# How can I stop a double click of the window title bar from maximizing a window of FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm annoyed that the I'm promised a fixed window that the user can't resize, but then of course they're allowed to double click the title bar to maximize this 'unresizable' window. How can I turn this off? Can I do it with winforms code, or must I go down to Win32?

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could set the `MaximizeBox` property of the form to false

Comment: I didn't think to do this, because the clickable 'maximize box' button was already hidden in this borderstyle.

Comment: Dont help with doubleclick for me

Comment: This answer is also useful when you removed all buttons from a Form with `ControlBox = false`. Need to set both to do it right.

Comment: Frustratingly, this only hides the specified box/control. It doesn't remove or disable the underlying functionality and double-clicking the title-bar will still function normally.

Answer (score 25):

You can disable the double-click message on a title bar in general (or change the default behavior which is maximizing the window). it works on any FormBorderStyle:

```
private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3; //double click on a title bar a.k.a. non-client area of the form

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
            {
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

[MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Cheers!

Comment: This is the actual answer, just removing the maximise box or controls will not prevent the event.

Answer (score 10):

/// 
        /// This is we are overriding base WIN32 window procedure to prevent the form from being moved by the mouse as well as resized by the mouse double click.
        /// 
        ///

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3; //double click on a title bar a.k.a. non-client area of the form

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:             //preventing the form from being moved by the mouse.
                int command = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MOVE)
                    return;
                break;
        }

       if(m.Msg== WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)       //preventing the form being resized by the mouse double click on the title bar.
        {
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;                   
            return;                   
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late to the party,  May help someone who is searching for the same.

```
private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3; //double click on a title bar a.k.a. non-client area of the form

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{

    switch (msg)
    {                
        case WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK:    //preventing the form being resized by the mouse double click on the title bar.
            handled = true;
            break;                
        default:
            break;
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just checked it in VB.Net. Below code worked for me.

```
Private Const Win_FormTitleDoubleClick As Integer = 163

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg = Win_FormTitleDoubleClick Then
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero
        Return
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Note: 163 is the event code

Answer (score 0):

I approached the problem slightly differently. First I removed the minimize and maximize options from the control box via the `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` properties as you'd expect.

Then I added the following `OnResizeEnd()` event and attached it to the Form's ResizeEnd event handler:

```
/// <summary>Locks the form to fill the screen that it's placed on and remain in that state as long as it's open.</summary>
private void GuiMain_ResizeEnd( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    this.Location = Screen.WorkingArea.Location;
    this.Size = Screen.WorkingArea.Size;
    this.MaximizedBounds = Screen.WorkingArea;
    this.MinimumSize = Screen.WorkingArea.Size;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

This solution necessarily relies on the existence of the following accessor which you can copy, or you can simply replace each instance of `Screen.` in the above with `Screen.FromHandle( this.Handle ).`

```
protected Screen Screen => Screen.FromHandle( this.Handle );
```

Obviously, if ironically, this actually keeps the form in the `FormWindowState.Normal` state, but it mimics the effect of maximization, and resets this fullscreen state after any attempt to change it.

Interestingly, due to the use of the `Screen.FromHandle()` settings (as opposed to hard-coded ones), you can actually drag the form from one display to another, whereupon it immediately "snaps" to fill *THAT* screen instead. Something I found quite handy, but which may require additional code to correct if you don't want that functionality in your application.