# Disable maximize / minimize on Form's double click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop a double click of the window title bar from maximizing a window of FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588540/how-can-i-stop-a-double-click-of-the-window-title-bar-from-maximizing-a-window-o)

I have a form which I've removed the **minimize** and **maximize** buttons from, set the `FormBorderStyle` to none, added [drag & drop behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14363217/1471381), but I want my form size to be static. Now form maximizes/minimizes on `Double Click`.

I searched but didn't find relevent answers, questions I came up with were about disabling minimize & maximize buttons.

I there a way that I tell my form *"Hei, would you ignore double click and maintain your size please?"* ?

Comment: I think the Minimize/Maximize on Double click of the Window title bar is native to windows os. Not sure though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `MaximumSize` and `MinimumSize`. If they both equal the same thing it should prevent the form from changing size.

Comment: To me, there's nothing about a Window's border that should dictate its size constraints. A border is only one possible way of maximizing/minimizing. It seems "hackier" to use that than to use  `MaximumSize` and `MinimumSize`.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Saved me a lot of trouble (^_^)

Answer (score 2):

if you can set FormBorderStyle from None to FixedSingle or Fixed3D it will prevent form maximixe on double click

Comment: FixedToolWindow and FixedDialog are also acceptable choices.

Comment: Although `FixedToolWindow` ironically will maximize when double-clicking the title bar (yes, even though it's "fixed" in size). You have to set the `MaximizeBox` property to `false` to turn off that functionality. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9588599/945456

Comment: @JeffBridgman Your method worked, THANK YOU!