# Disabling maximizing form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to disable maximizing form in C#. My form's border style is None, so I don't need to disable MaximizeBox (but I disabled it). But after applying:

```
private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
        private const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;
        private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref message);

            if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && (int)message.Result == HTCLIENT)
                message.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
        }
```

to make my form be able to drag, it could be maximized by double clicking anywhere. I need to disable maximizing form. How do I do that?

Comment: If you remove the FormBorderStyle.None then your code works (and disable MaximizeBox)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701191/disable-maximize-minimize-on-forms-double-click

Comment: @HansKeﬆing They are equal to 0.

Comment: @Steve Well yes, but border style in my project must be None.